# Exception Description CustomerTransaction] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.Long] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field id]

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create my first project with JPA and I am having some trouble when declaring a @manytoone relationship. This seems to be a common issue and I have already tried a couple of solutions without luck.

The logic behind is that one customer can have many transaction but one trasaction can have only one customer.

This is my code. CustomerTrasaction

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "CustomerTransaction")//Specifiying the table name
public class CustomerTransaction   implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   /*Declaring the relation ManytoOne and joining customer basic information*/

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumns({

                        @JoinColumn(name = "firstName;", referencedColumnName = "firstName;"),
                        @JoinColumn(name = "lastName;", referencedColumnName = "lastName;"),

        })
```

Customer class

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    //Customer attributes
    private Long id ;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String customerEmail; 
    private String phone; 
    private String customerID;

    //Declaring one to many relation
    @OneToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}) 
    private List<CustomerTransaction> customerT; //List of customer transactions
```

Persistance"just in case"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.mycompany.carsales.Customer</class>
    <class>com.mycompany.carsales.Cars</class>
    <class>com.mycompany.carsales.CustomerTransaction</class>
    <class>com.mycompany.carsales.FamilyCars</class>
    <class>com.mycompany.carsales.SportCars</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Cars;create=true"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Error message

```
Exception Description: [class com.mycompany.carsales.CustomerTransaction] uses a non-entity [class java.lang.Long] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field id].
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete, the `@id` annotation in `CustomerTransaction` annotates nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your classes need to be correctly annotated or have correct fields. Your first issue is that your CustomerTransaction doesn't decare the fields that are you are annotating.
Secondly you need to annotate the fields in your Customer that you are referencing in your join columns, and adding an inverse join column for reference.

CustomerTransaction class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_transaction")  //Specifiying the table name
    public class CustomerTransaction   implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   /*Declaring the relation ManytoOne and joining customer basic information*/
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_transaction_join",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName="id"), 
          uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"transaction_id", "customer_id"}))

    })
    private Customer customer;
```

Notice the uniqueConstraints  - this disallows a duplicate entry which means a transaction can only have one customer.

Customer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "customer_email")
    private String customerEmail; 

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone; 

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private String customerID;

    //Declaring one to many relation
    @OneToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}) 
    private List<CustomerTransaction> customerTransations;
```